# Getting individual PDF pages with PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I have a PDF document that has 32 pages and need to convert each page to a JPG image. How can I process each PDF page separately instead of a whole document? I've tried doing some research to no luck. I looked at the [PHP.net PDF](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php) documentation and it doesn't seem like there's a way for me to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Using ImageMagick will do this for you...

```
$image = new Imagick("temp/{$filename}.pdf[0]");
```

Were the array [0] is the page (0 being the first page)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Adobe Acrobat, you can just use it to export the PDF to JPG files, one for each page.